# Hide menu when user clicks outside of the button?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have tried many different solutions but none have worked. My way of doing this is a bit different from everyone else's and I think that's why theirs wont work for me.

I have this:

```
   function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';

   else
      e.style.display = 'block';

    }
```

I want to make the pulled down menu disappear not only when you click on the button again to close it, but also when you click anywhere else outside. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You tagged this as jQuery... where is the jQuery? Also can you provide HTML?

Comment: Maybe [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it?rq=1) helps you.

Comment: Yeah sorry about the jQuery tag, I meant to put Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i hope it will work for you:

```
         $('body').not($('#menu').find('*'))
         .bind('click',function(){
            $("#menu").css('top', '-1000px');
            $("#menu").css('left', '-1000px');
         });
```

Lets handle clicks on the body, and if the click happens NOT anywhere on the menu, do your hiding

Comment: I think I figured it out actually, thank you for your answer!